# Connection must be valid and open VB.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to connect my MySQL to my VB.net.
I am only using Login Form.
I have given the code but the code gives me this error message: `Connection must be valid and open`

This is my code:

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Login 
    Dim MysqlConn As MySqlConnection
    Dim Command As MySqlCommand

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        MysqlConn = New MySqlConnection
        MysqlConn.ConnectionString ="server=db4free.net;port=3306;userid=exd****;password=****;database=exd****"
        Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader

    Try
        MysqlConn.Open()
        Dim Query As String
        Query = "select * from member where Username='" & UsernameTxt.Text & "' and Password='" & PasswordTxt.Text & "' "
        Command = New MySqlCommand
        Reader = Command.ExecuteReader
        Dim count As Integer
        count = 0

        While Reader.Read
            count = count + 1
        End While

        If count = 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Correct !")
        ElseIf count > 1 Then
            MessageBox.Show("Duplicate !")
        Else
            MessageBox.Show("Not Correct !")
        End If

        MysqlConn.Close()

    Catch ex As Exception
         MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        MysqlConn.Dispose()
    End Try

    End Sub

End Class
```

Can anyone help me to fix that?  Thanks.

Comment: What did you try to solve this? This seems like we should debug you program. Also, please take a look at the [tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At no point do you associate your `MysqlConn` nor  `Query` to your `Command` before trying to call `ExecuteReader` on it. As such, it doesn't have a valid connection at that time.

Answer (score 3):

To associate your `Query` and `Command` with the connection you need to do this:

```
Command = New MySqlCommand(Query, MysqlConn)
```

You can then perform operations to retrieve the data you need.

Comment: ahaha, maybe because i so bad from coding and dont know about that :/

Answer (score 0):

Query = "select * from member where Username='" & UsernameTxt.Text & "' and Password='" & PasswordTxt.Text & "' ", **nombredelaconexion**