# Using textbox input to insert username and password to connection string VB

Tags: mysql, vb.net, string, textbox, connection

Im making a program that uses an MySql database.

Right now i am using Visual Basic and Visual Studio 2013, and i am pretty new to programming. Other than html, css, javascript, and some php.

Now i want to use 2 textboxes to insert username and password to the connection string. So:

```
server=IP ADRESS;userid="TextBox4 input";password="TextBox1 input";persistsecurityinfo=True;database=DB
```

This is pretty much the connection string i have now. Just with all the info so everyone can see them. Now at the user id and password i want to be able to use 2 different textboxes to insert the data in there.

Anyone who has an idea how to do that?

[THIS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9cCZF.png) is my connection string right now. In project/projectname properties/settings.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You want to use `TextBox4.Text` for both, the userid and the password?

Comment: No, sorry userid=textbox4 password=textbox1

Comment: Here goes Captain Obvious - In the picture, it does not work because there is no user id as well as a password. This is where the input from the TextBoxes will go.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Dim conn As New MySqlConnection
conn .ConnectionString = "server=IP ADRESS; " & _
                         "userid=" & Trim(txtUserName.Text) & "; " & _  /*'put your textbox name that holds username */
                         "password=" & Trim(txtPassWord.Text) & ";" & _  /*'put your textbox name that holds password */
                         "persistsecurityinfo=True;" & _
                         "database=DB"
```

Comment: This works when i just do a conn.open(). But how do i use this data in my DataGridViews?

Comment: @Thomsen1707 just elaborate _how do i use this data in my DataGridViews?_ , what data a _conn_? or _user/pwd_ ?

Comment: I need to put data from my MySql database inside a DataGridView. Not user/pwd, but some stock data. How do i put this data inside the DataGridView with code?

Comment: @Thomsen1707 From your comments what I understood is _You have to declare connection string as a global variable so that It could access when you need to declare a connection to access data from DB_

Comment: Revamp your question with actual need and put code from where you want to fetch usr/pwd

Comment: I am making a program that needs a MySql database, therefore i wanted an authentication FOR that MySql database, which i got from your code. Now i need a way to get that data in my MySql table FROM MySql TO my program.

Comment: @Thomsen1707 Plethora of tuts/resources are available in web that helps you.Here is a one - http://stackoverflow.com/a/27635113/3682599

Answer (score 1):

You can use a `MySqlConnectionStringBuilder`:

```
Dim conBuilder As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnectionStringBuilder()
conBuilder.Server = "IP ADRESS"
conBuilder.PersistSecurityInfo = True
conBuilder.Database = "DB"
conBuilder.UserID = txtUserID.Text
conBuilder.Password = txtPassword.Text
Dim connectionString = conBuilder.ToString()
```

Note that i've renamed your textboxes to something more meaningful.

Comment: But i am using the wizard to connect to my MySql database. Not a connection string in the form1 code. Will i be able to use this for it still?

Comment: @Thomsen1707: where and for what do you use the connection-wizard? You can use my code without wizard. Just assign the connection-string to the object for which you need the connection-string, f.e. a `MySqlConnection`. No wizard needed.

Comment: Yea should have said - in visual studio 2013 in data sources. Felt much more easy